# Compile Error CS1001. Converting Java to C#

Tags: c#

CS1001 = Identifier Expected

I took a snippet of code from Java that I would like to test in C#. It has a formula for calculating Experience needed to level up in a Video Game project I would like to use. I have just recently began teaching myself code, so converting this was trial and error for me, but I have eliminated the other 13 Errors and this one has me stuck.

Missing an identifier seems like a pretty rudimentary issue but it is also vague and i'm not sure when to begin to research. I have comment where the error occurs.

Any hints?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    float points = 0; 
    double output = 0; // Output, XP total at level
    float minLevel = 2; // First level to Display
    int maxLevel = 100; // Last Level to Display
    int lvl = 0;

    void Main()
    {

        for (lvl = 1; lvl <= maxLevel; lvl++)
        {
            points += Math.Floor(lvl + 300 * Math.Pow(2, lvl / 7.)); // Compile Error CS1001 at "));"
            if (lvl >= minLevel)
                Console.WriteLine("Level " + (lvl) + " - " + output + " EXP");
            output = Math.Floor(points / 4);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Original JavaScript Code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
document.close();
document.open();
document.writeln('Begin JavaScript output:');
document.writeln('<PRE>');

points = 0;
output = 0;
minlevel = 2; // first level to display
maxlevel = 200; // last level to display

for (lvl = 1; lvl <= maxlevel; lvl++)
{
  points += Math.floor(lvl + 300 * Math.pow(2, lvl / 7.));
  if (lvl >= minlevel)
    document.writeln('Level ' + (lvl) + ' - ' + output + ' xp');
  output = Math.floor(points / 4);
}

document.writeln('</PRE>');
document.close();
// -->
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: points += Math.Floor(lvl + 300 * Math.Pow(2, lvl / 7.0));

Comment: `7.)`? shouldn't that be `7.0)`?

Comment: Java !== JavaScript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't look like the only problem... :)

See inline comments:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        float points = 0; 
        double output = 0;
        float minLevel = 2;
        int maxLevel = 100;
        int lvl = 0;

        void Main() //<-- Bad entry point public static void Main()
        {

            for (lvl = 1; lvl <= maxLevel; lvl++)
            {
                points += (float)Math.Floor(lvl + 300 * Math.Pow(2, lvl / 7.)); // <-- You have to explicitly specify the mantissa if you have a '.' is should be 7.0 or 7f
                            //^--- You also need to cast to a float here because the expression evaluates to a double
                if (lvl >= minLevel)
                    Console.WriteLine("Level " + (lvl) + " - " + output + " EXP");
                output = Math.Floor(points / 4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The template uses `static void Main()` and when defining variables i learned had to also define them as `static` so I tested removing static from both parts and i was surprised when I read no errors. I forgot to replace them.

Comment: Some _build errors_ will only show up in VS when you actually press `build`